# Compiling error Nutch on HDP

Tags: hadoop, nutch

I just started using nutch, and after spending yesterday to figure out
how to run nutch on the newest HDP (2.3.2) vm i ran into some
problems.

Building the source directly, went fine,
but after the local first run i ran into the

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.gora.hbase.store.HBaseStore
```

i got this error solved with also adding the hbase jars to the
classpath but now i always run into an error i can't really get my
head around

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
org.apache.hadoop.hbase.HTableDescriptor.addFamily(Lorg/apache/hadoop/hbase/HColumnDescriptor;)V
```

on stack overflow it is suggested to add the hbase libs to the class
path, but i already did that, to fix the classnotfound exception.

I just started with hadoop, so it might be an error spawned from the
lack of knowledge of the system.

Anybody got an idea how to get nutch up and running on HDP?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try these steps :

1. copy $HABSE_HOME/lib/ to nutch.x.x.x/lib
2. make sure to copy the hbase-site.xml from hbase config to nutch cofig dir.
3. run "ant clean" and "ant runtime"

hth.